# How to use mapped props in connect function - redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I would like to use my mapped listId in my deleteListSettingsCustomSubjectLine function. I thought I can use ownProps for that but it returns undefined. Can someone explain how it should be done?

```
@connect(state => {
    return {
        listId: state.views.ListSettings.listSettings.listId,
    }
}, (dispatch, ownProps) {
     return {
         onCustomSubjectLineDelete: () => {
         const {listId} = ownProps; //undefined
         dispatch(actions
                    .deleteListSettingsCustomSubjectLine(listId));
         }
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**NEW:**

I'd recommend passing the `listId` property as an argument to the `onCustomSubjectLineDelete` and calling it as `onCustomSubjectLineDelete(listId);`

Then the definition would be:

```
onCustomSubjectLineDelete(listId) {
    dispatch(actions.deleteListSettingsCustomSubjectLine(listId);
}
```

**OLD, bad answer:**

Here's a simplified example (using only the first argument for `mapStateToProps`). Mapping to props is exactly that, you can access the mapped properties via the `this.props` property.

```
@connect(state => {
     return {
         listId: state.views.ListSettings.listSettings.listId,
     }
})
class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
       const { listId } = this.props;
       return (
          <div>{listId}</div>
       );
    }
}
```

I'd recommend taking a look [at the Redux usage with React documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) as well.